# color coding inside bash script: text printed in normal colow

Tags: bash, unix

I'm having an issue with printing color coded messages as an output to the shell script I'm running.

The script performs some tasks for which it is accustomed to print error logs. These error logs aren't printed on verbose rather directed to a log file.

The snipped printing the error message in color is like this:

```
echo -e "\e[1;33m errorMessage=Number of records doesn't match with the actual record count \e[0m" >&2
```

The error message is printed in color if I print directly on verbose. But if I pass it to a log file, there's no color; rather it is read as a literal character.

```
^[[1;33m errorMessage=Number of records doesn't match with the actual record count ^[[0m
```

Is there anyway I can persist this color within the log files?

Comment: You can read the log file with `less -R`, for example. But the "raw" characters have to be there; the colour information is contained in them and nowhere else.

Comment: That does work. Thanks!
What do you mean by "raw" characters, if it's not other than the color codes?

Comment: Is there any other option to add permanent color codes to such messages?

Comment: @knowone The "color codes" are just sequences of ASCII characters that *some programs* interpret as color codes. But other programs don't; they might convert the characters to a printable format (what your log viewer does), or they might do something else. `less -R` will simply pass them through directly (see the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less) -- the relevant section is a ways down), and then your terminal program will interpret them as color codes and display the following text in color.

Comment: If you want to be able to look at the logs with vim and have the colour codes be properly interpreted, you could look at [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7695/how-to-make-vim-display-colors-as-indicated-by-color-codes).

Comment: Understood. Thanks Benjamin, Gordon.